# python-shell from nodejs write to file

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to do this:

`python /path/tofile/myfile.py > /path/to/anotherfile.txt`

```
var path = require('path');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');


var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  scriptPath:'/path/tofile',
  command: '/path/to/anotherfile.txt',
  args: [1]
};

PythonShell.run('myfile.py', options, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('results: %j', results);   
    });
```

python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 

for v in sys.argv[1]: 
    print( 'Hello!')
```

So,if I run it , I can see the `results: ["Hello!"]`

but nothing is written to the file.

And what if I have more args, like:

`python /path/tofile/myfile.py > /path/to/anotherfile.txt > /another/path.txt`

(I am not sure about the `command` and `args` in options)